# Xamarin Forms And MonoTouch Incompatibility

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

After updating Xamarin.Forms nuget package to latest stable version (**2.0.1.6505**), the following error occurs in build:

> Failed to resolve "System.Void
>   UIKit.UITableView::set_CellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth(System.Boolean)"
>   reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"

I am using following platform:

**Windows:**

jdk-7u71

gtk-sharp-2.12.26

XamarinStudio-5.9.5.9-0

Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.11.836

**Mac:**

MonoFramework-MDK-4.0.3.20

XamarinStudio-5.9.5.9-0

mono-android-5.1.5-3

monotouch-8.10.4.46

XCode-6.4(6E35b)

Comment: While the NuGet package is up-to-date, your development environment does not seem to be. Mono is now 4.2.1 while Xamarin bits should also be newer than yours.

Comment: As @LexLi mentions, you may want to upgrade your development environment in Xamarin Studio since Xamarin [just released a new version of nearly all of their components](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59995/stable-release-xamarin-4-cycle-6-service-release-1).

By the way, if you have a look at the link above, you'll notice that the version of mono that has been released is in fact 4.2.2.30, not 4.2.1.

Comment: @DavidKristianLaundav thanks for your comment. I was using latest version of xamarin platform before downgrading to current version because suggested by a Xamarin support man. I got the following error with no solution before downgrading:

Failed to load AOT module 'mscorlib' while running in aot-only mode: compiled against GC ������, while the current runtime uses GC sgen.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your comment. I described in comment above, why am I using an older version of xamarin.

Comment: @FarzinZaker then you should also avoid the latest NuGet package. Try an older version that matches your Xamarin bits.